# Xcode: How to exclude a path from Search Navigator

Tags: regex, xcode, svn, configuration

In Xcode, in this case 4.x, how would you go about excluding a path (or a path containing a pattern) from search results?

My use case:

My project is SVN controlled. Whenever I search for text (such as a function name), I often get irrelevant results returned from ".svn-base" files (which are used for making local diff's between your working copy and the last checked out revision).

I have setup a custom scope where the 'Location' 'is within the file or folder' 'Classes' (a subfolder I want to search). There doesn't seem to be a way to say "And Not..." or "And where path does not match". There is a "matches regex" and I feel the answer may lie around Look-arounds... Maybe something like `(?!\.svn)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an extra condition in the settings of my custom scopes I use this:

```
^((?!\.svn).)*$
```

Check out this very good explanation here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)

Comment: I have a 260MB text file in my workspace that slows searching down tremendously. Now I can ignore it while searching! Thanks.